# SQL Server: Merging Two Tables Together & Sending Output to Temp Table Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, union, temp

I'm trying to merge two SQL tables together on a unique column and send it to a temp table.  However, I get an error (see below).

When I do the left join below, it creates two "UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER" columns which breaks my INTO statement.

```
    SELECT * 
    INTO #temp_table 
    FROM #df_EVENT5_a as t1
    LEFT JOIN #df_ERA_Final as t2 ON t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER
```

Error: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER' in table '#temp_table' is specified more than once.

Comment: include column names in `select` and give them different aliases.

Comment: how do I give them different names ... is it SELECT [COL] AS [NEWNAME]?

Comment: yes.you should do that.

Comment: it won't let me do that because that column hasn't been created yet so I can't put it in my select statement

Comment: You are selecting 2 columns with the same name (t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER  ) . Use a set list of columns instead of the *.

Comment: can you show me the actual code of what you would do please?

Comment: please show me in code if possible ... I'm confused by your text comments

Answer (score 0):

It's because that column name exists in both tables. You can't have two columns in a single table with the same name.

Your query is the same as saying

```
SELECT 
    t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER 
    ,t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER 
    --list all other columns...
INTO #temp_table 
FROM #df_EVENT5_a as t1
LEFT JOIN #df_ERA_Final as t2 ON t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER
```

This means `#temp_table` would have two columns named `UNIQUE_IDENTIFER`. So, remove the `*` and list the columns you want explicitly from each table... and alias any columns with the same name...

```
SELECT 
    FIRST_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER 
    ,SECOND_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER 
    --list all other columns...
INTO #temp_table 
FROM #df_EVENT5_a as t1
LEFT JOIN #df_ERA_Final as t2 ON t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER
```